# compound adjectives with "-made"

Tags: adjectives, compounds, word-formation

Can compound adjectives ending in -made denote something that is made of or from a material?
For example, is "seaweed-made packaging" okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. "-made" denotes who/how something was made, not the material from which it was made. Hence a "man-made disaster" or "home-made bread".

"Seaweed-based packaging" is what you're after.